# How can browsers resolve icon libraries that aren't specifically referenced in the frontend code?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Every time I see some JS/UI magic, I am compelled to research it until I understand it.

I recently came across an awesome [developer's personal website](http://www.shannabarnard.com) and noticed that she is using [Mdi icons](https://s3.amazonaws.com/kantan-dresssed-demos/demos/ives/blue_preview/007_icons@fa-lightbulb-o%252F004_mdi_icons.html). If you look at the source code, you'll see several different usages of them:

- `mdi-content-send`
- `mdi-content-archive`
- `mdi-navigation-chevron-left`
- `mdi-navigation-chevron-right`
- etc.

What I can't figure out is: where is access to this Mdi icons lib? It is never specified as a reference/import in the HTML, CSS or JS: so how is my browser able to resolve it?

Comment: What you mean it's not referenced? There's a link to http://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons in the head section.

Comment: Thanks @pawel (+1) but those Material Icons are not the same as the Mdi icons I provided a link for above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's referenced in a CSS file. Check http://www.shannabarnard.com/css/materialize.css. There is a font called "Material-Design-Icons" included. The CSS classes are mapped to this font using pseudo attributed as `:before`.

```
.mdi-content-archive:before {
    content: "\e6ff";
}
```

The code `\e6ff` is a letter which is in this case an Icon instead of an letter.